# How to determine if object is loaded or not?

Tags: client-object-model, list-view, view

It's very easy. 
Just share some pieces of advice with me.

Example - I need to load a view of a list:

```
var view = _list.Views.GetByTitle("title");

//but returned view always is not null
if(view != null){
     //do smth
}
```

Regardless of existence this view `GetByTitle()` returns a non null object.
So my question is how to determine is view loaded(existed) or not ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use "[ServerObjectIsNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee546762.aspx)" property to check if the server object is null

Ex:

```
if(!view.ServerObjectIsNull.HasValue)
```

Try using below function to validate the list view.

```
public bool IsViewExist(string siteUrl, string listTitle, string viewTitle)
    {
        bool isViewExist = false;
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
        context.Load(list);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ViewCollection viewColl = list.Views;
        context.Load(viewColl,
            views => views.Include(
                view => view.Title));
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.View view in viewColl)
        {
           if(view.Title.Equals(viewTitle))
           {
               isViewExist = true;
               break;
           }

        }

        return isViewExist;
    }
```

Comment: but after using this property i get error

Comment: and i don't why this property gets me null regrdless that the object actually exists

Comment: Please see the updated answer: This function could be useful to validate the list view.

Comment: @isxaker Did you execute `context.load` and `context.executeQuery` before checking `ServerObjectIsNull`?

Comment: Ok. Obviously it is a key point. I mean load and execute. Do I have to call these methods for a viewCollection or a view ? And thanks for updated answer, but I had almost the same code. And my main goal was to prevent using foreach =))

Comment: And moreover, I get 'The specified view is invalid' exception when i try to Load() and ExecuteQuery() the view which mthod GetByTittle() returns